# Adobe Premiere CS6 stuck at 0% exporting still images

Tags: video, editing, premiere

I am creating a slideshow in Premiere so it's just a bunch of images with transitions. When exporting to any kind of format or codec, it would get stuck "Encoding 0%" forever and freeze afterwards. This doesn't happen when I put videos in the sequence. As soon as there is 1 image, the whole thing just won't export.

Any idea why?

Comment: Gonna need more information.  Does anything max out?  CPU, Memory, etc.  Does it seem like the computer is trying to do something or does it just stop working altogether?

Comment: @AJHenderson CPU is maxed out. And I have to force quit the application. This is on MBP Retina with 16GB RAM

Comment: Have you tried rendering the work area prior to export?  Does the same thing happen when rendering work area?  What happens if you try exporting through Adobe Media Encoder?

Comment: @AJHenderson The preview rendering is looking corrupted (just noise, sometimes I see my desktop in there too) But if I double-click the area, the image shows up. The preview also shows up fine on the Export window.

Comment: sounds like maybe something is wrong with the rendering engine itself.  Have you tried reinstalling Premiere?